# How to know if the strings.xml is the default file?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 7 strings in the project like this

```
strings.xml //This is the default
strings.xml (en)
strings.xml (ar)
strings.xml (es)
strings.xml (de)
strings.xml (it)
strings.xml (ru)
```

And I have JSON in server like this

```
[
  {
    "default": {
      "Message": "..."
    },
    "en": {
      "Message": "..."
    },
    "ar": {
      "Message": "..."
    },
    "es": {
      "Message": "..."
    },
    "de": {
      "Message": "..."
    },
    "it": {
      "Message": "..."
    },
    "ru": {
      "Message": "..."
    }
  }
]
```

I want to read the message according to device language but the problem is how to know if the strings.xml is the default file to show default message from JSON?

Comment: try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22632022/12543430

Comment: @D_K I can get the message from JSON using this [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale#getLanguage()) but how to know it is time to get the default message? Because that method will give me the language code only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70103261/11880323) method.

In summary, you declare in each `strings.xml` a `string` telling which one is currently being used.